# Select entre 2 models Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Gostaria de saber como faço uma queryset que retorne todos os "Cartoes"(model2) vinculados ao meu "Colaborador"(model1)?

Models:

```
class Colaborador(models.Model):
    # dados pessoais do colaborador
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sobrenome = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    data_nascimento = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)


class Cartoes(models.Model):
    colaborador = models.ForeignKey(Colaborador, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cartao = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CARTOES_CHOICES, default='nenhum')
    validade = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Exemplo SQL -> "SELECT * FROM Cartoes WHERE colaborador = ' colaborador do primeiro model ' "

Answer (score -2):

Consegui o resultado que queria com a seguinte query:

```
 cartoes = Cartoes.objects.filter(colaborador=id)
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).